# How to inject an HttpClient CustomDelegatingHandler in dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net

I have a custom delegating handler for logging purposes:

```
    public class LoggingDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler {

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //my logging
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

I've been tring to inject it in my dependency injection like so:

```
        services.AddHttpClient(nameof(MyAuthorityClient),
                c => { c.BaseAddress = new Uri(myOptions.BaseUri); })
            .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(x =>
                x.WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryAttempt)))
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler<MyClientHttpHandler>()
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<LoggingDelegatingHandler>();
```

It seems to compile. But when the execution hits this code:

```
ar response = await client.GetAsync("/my/api/path");
```

the debugger never arrives to the `SendAsync` method in my `LoggingDelegatingHandler`.

At first, I thought it's because I am calling `GetAsync` and my overridden method is `SendAsync` but then I have read that it should still hit `SendAsync`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

1. Define your custom delegating handler by creating a new class that derives from DelegatingHandler and overrides its SendAsync method

   ```
    public class AuthHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly string _authToken;

        public AuthHeaderHandler(string authToken)
        {
            _authToken = authToken;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authToken);
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
   ```
2. Next, register the HttpClient and its associated delegating handler in the service collection. You can do this in the ConfigureServices method of your startup class.

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register the AuthHeaderHandler with the service collection
        services.AddTransient<AuthHeaderHandler>(sp => new AuthHeaderHandler(Configuration["AuthToken"]));

        // Register the HttpClient with the AuthHeaderHandler
        services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient").AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthHeaderHandler>();

        // Add other services and dependencies as needed...
     }
   ```
3. Inject the HttpClient into your class or service using constructor injection.

   ```
   public class MyController : Controller
   {
       private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
       public MyController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
       {
           _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyHttpClient");
       }

       // Use the _httpClient instance to send HTTP requests...
   }
   ```